# How do I Queue Distributed Computing Jobs at home using SQL?

Tags: sql-server, queue, sql-server-express, labview

I'm using an application written in LabVIEW (an engineering software framework/programming language) to run about twenty thousand simulations. Each simulation takes about 5 mins to complete, and results will be dumped into a database hosted in a laptop in my local network. I'm using SQL Express as my database.

Each simulation job has a set of starting parameters that will be passed to the application. This could be as simple as a string of characters that the application would parse into valid simulation characteristics, but I'm not sure exactly how to structure this.

Because the simulations would take about 3 months to run on one computer, I want to add in the capability for the database computer to be able to "schedule" jobs. That way, I can run the application on any computer in my local network (I have 5 available) for a few simulations, and stop simulations when I need to use it for other things. The database computer will hand out these jobs as they get requested by the application, as well as continuously run jobs itself.

How would I go about setting up this queue from an SQL point of view? The framework I currently have in mind would work something like this: Database has 3 tables in addition to tables used to store simulation data. The tables contain CompletedJobs,RunningJobs, and JobsToRun. The application would request a job from JobsToRun, and place that job's ID into the RunningJobs table. It would then parse the job's ID for relevant information, run the simulation, and if it exits without errors, move the job ID to the CompletedJobs table.

Would this work?

Comment: The application written in labview.... its only interaction with the database is that it dumps its results there? I guess you run this as an EXE and pass parameters into it on the command line? Please provide more technical details - how do you run this right now? Also keep in mind SQL Express does not have SQL Agent which is quite helpful in this kind of remote execution situation.

Comment: LabVIEW has functionality for accessing databases. So it would do a quick select min(jobID) where jobstatus = ToRun to get a jobID. This integer would run through a parser to turn into simulation starting parameters. During simulation, it would write to the database (or maybe to some kind of cache), and when simulation completes, it marks the job as complete and it would loop back. This would continue until all jobs are completed or the user requests the application to stop.

Comment: If LabView can use a central job queue table then it sounds like you have it mostly worked out already. Is there a piece of code you are having trouble with or are you trying to settle on a database design?

Comment: The job table would actually be in the database. And yeah, this is my first DB design, so I'm pretty clueless.

Comment: Assuming you build a 'queue' table along the lines of @nekomatic description... can LabView read from this table directly and start a process or do you need an intermediate piece of software to identify the process record and kick off LabView?

Comment: It can. It compiles an exe that can run the code on any windows machine.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the need for three tables - why not have one table, `Jobs`, with a `JobStatus` field that can take values (e.g.) **ToRun**, **Running**, **Completed**, and perhaps **Failed** - you can probably think of others. When a simulation starts a new job, it changes the status to **Running**, when it completes the job it changes it again to **Completed** or **Failed**.

You might want fields for `StartTime` and `EndTime`, perhaps `ErrorCode` if your simulation might fail with different types of error? What does the output of the simulation consist of - should you store a filename of the output file, or even upload the output data itself as a BLOB? Let the database take care of assigning each job a unique ID, which would be the primary key for the database table.

What sort of data actually are the starting parameters? If you can store them in database fields, do that. You could put those in a second table if you wanted, and have your `Jobs` table refer to the parameter set's ID in the job parameters table.

Comment: The starting parameters are floating point numbers, enums and 2D arrays. The simulation logs data values of a bunch of things during every cycle count of simulation. Here's a sample simulation log: http://i.imgur.com/HbbfEzF.png

This would all fall under one jobID

Comment: This is a comment and not an answer but.... I agree - it seems to me you only need one table with a status. You might also need some data structures defining your processing nodes (i.e. a list of your laptops), and which ones are busy